# Display a warning message when the session has expired

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I want to display a warning message when the session has expired (15 minutes) but without refresh a page manually

I have this:

```
$Mysession = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$Mysession->setData("s", "v");
$myDeviceId = $Mysession->getData("s");
$Mysession->setData("time", time());

//the condition   900= 15minutes
 if((time() - $Mysession->getData("time")) > 900){
 echo "Session expired";}
```

here its works but the message appears just when i refresh the page.

I thought to add this but is not a good idea

```
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 5; URL=$url1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to achieve is *client-side*, not server-side.

On page load, you could set a timer in javascript. When the timer expires, display your message.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Session expired');
}, 900); // 900 = 15 * 60
```

Of course, you may prefer to give a warning message a few minutes *before* timeout to give the user a chance to refresh or do something to continue his session; for exaample, you could make an ajax request to the server to refresh his session and reset the timer. And you might display your message using something more elegant than just `alert()`. And on expiration, you may wish to redirect the user directly to a fresh login page with a message that he has been expired. Lots of possibilities. But this example gives the core idea.